# How to match APIs with minimum Sdks

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on an app and trying to run it using the android studio virtual devices. When I get to the "Select Deployment Target" I select one of my virtual devices (Nexus 5X API 25), but I get an error "minSdk(API 1, API 25 preview) != deviceSdk(API 25)". I've tried changing the minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, and compileSdkVersion to a few different numbers: 19, 24, N, etc. None of these work though and the "API 1" part of the error never changes. I've also tried using different virtual devices with different APIs: 23, 24, 25, but none of them work either.

[Here is my build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnbu8.jpg)

This problem is also pretty recent and I don't think I changed much from when it was working to when it stopped working. Any help with this problem would be appreciated!

Comment: minSdkVersion is supposed to be an int, not a string. Remove the '' and just put `minSdkVersion 25` on that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

minSdkVerision should be a interger not a string. So, Change your minSdkVersion in your build.gradle to a interger as shown below

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 25
```

hope this helps.